# Setting up hierarchical, self-referencing model in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to create a self-referencing org table in Entity Framework v6 code-first - and I can't seem to get it right... (so far I always worked with the EF 4.0 visual designer).

I have this class (that corresponds to a SQL Server table):

```
[Table("Organisation")]
public partial class Organisation
{
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentOrgId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentOrgId")]
    public virtual Organisation Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty standard stuff - and this is my `DbContext` derived class which should set up this self-referencing hierarchy:

```
public partial class HierarchyCtx : DbContext
{
    public HierarchyCtx() : base("name=HierarchyCtx") 
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisation { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentOrgId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); 
    }
}
```

Now I added a few rows to my SQL Server table, but when trying to load these entries, I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
>   Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
>   Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
>   Invalid column name 'ParentOrganisation_OrganisationId'.

Not entirely sure what's happening here.... what is `Discriminator` (a column I do not have) and why do I need it? How to add it? And why is EF trying to find a column `ParentOrganisation_OrganisationId` when I set the model up to use `ParentOrgId` as foreign key column??

This is a bit of a mystery to me..... anyone out there which has successfully done this in EF code-first before? What am I missing?

Comment: `Discriminator` column is indication of object hierarchy. You have `partial` modifier on your entity class, are you sure there isn't additional code not shown here? Also the database is up to date reflecting the above entity setup?

Comment: @IvanStoev: no, there's nothing else - no object hierarchy, no inheritance - this was generated by the EF wird "code-first from database" - so yes, I'm sure it's in sync with the database ....

Comment: There must be something else. I copy/pasted the above in my EF test environment, run it once, it created the table with expected columns/keys, I've entered some data and then invoked `db.Organisation.ToList()` and it works w/o any problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev: yeah - there is - stupid me ..... I wasn't descending `Organsation` from anything else - but I had a class that descended from `Organisation`, and that's what caused all of this..... thanks for the pointers! And additional brain and two more eyes most often help !

Comment: Hehe, no problem, it happens to all of us all the time :)

Comment: @marc_s - Came across this in a cleanup. Looks like you found a solution (in the comments) and can self-answer + accept?